# On ajax error, cache and try later

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, websocket, local-storage

I have a mobile project where I have to send ajax-requests one after the other. The project is using a mobile internet connection (egde, 3G), so it can happen that I lost the connection and I have to cache the failed request (in the localStorage), check at intervals for a valid connection and try again the request.

At the same time other requests come in (from the Browser), so I have to cache the requests in a queue and send them whole in a row.

Sorry for my bad Englisch, I hope you can understand my problem.

Any suggestions? Are there any libraries for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use below logic.
1. Create a array which will hold status of your ajax request.
2. Once you make a request add particular request to array and it results(response recieved) to false.
3. Once you recieve response from that request update the array and its results(response recieved) as true.
4. Read this array after particular time and send request again for false once.